# Open CSV File And Go Straight To Spreadsheet

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, csv, libreoffice

Part of my software issues various commands to open and view different file types. For instance I use `atril` for PDFs and `eom` for PNGs.
However I have a slight problem with CSV files. I can open them with `soffice –calc <filepath>` but each time it goes through the Import stage.
Is there a way I can avoid this, to avoid the risk of users creating issues, as the format is consistent and the only separator I need to include is the comma <kbd>,</kbd>?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method to skip importing would be to convert the file to a format that can be read without importing - so for instance:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to ods --outdir /tmp tblIssues.csv
soffice --view /tmp/tblIssues.ods
rm /tmp/tblIssues.ods
```

This converts the file `tblIssues.csv` to a ODS spreadsheet, saves it to `/tmp` and opens it in Libreoffice. Once it has finished it removes the converted file (optional).

The `--view` option opens the file as read-only, and also hides the GUI elements needed for editing, making LibreOffice more practical as a viewer.

You could also use other formats, such as PDF (`--convert-to pdf`) and then you can use another viewer like `atril`.

Note with I think the libreoffice convert command may use the settings used by the user last in the Importer, so if it is set to use a delimiter other than `,` it may not work.

Also, you can modify the commands to...

- hide output:

  ```
  COMMAND > /dev/null 2>&1
  ```
- separate from the terminal:

  ```
  COMMAND & disown
  ```

Comment: This worked straight out of the box and is now implemented.

Comment: Just an observation. If I convert to a speadsheet format, with the correct extension, the soffice --view command opens it up in 'calc' mode.  However if it does not have the correct extension it opens it in 'write' mode, even if I use the '--calc' option, but if you click on it with File Viewer it opens in 'calc' mode!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install unoconv (just once)

   - On Ubuntu run `sudo apt-get install unoconv`
   - On RHL/CentOS run `sudo yum install unoconv`
2. To convert on command-line or batch-mode (non-interactively)

   - unoconv -f pdf /pathto/file.csv /pathto/file.pdf 2>/dev/null

THAT'S IT!

Notes:

I pipe standard error to /dev/null because I get an error that 'looks' like the conversion failed, but it actually succeeds.  When I run `unoconv -f csv /tmp/this.csv /tmp/this.pdf` an error outputs:

`unoconv: UnoException during export phase:
 Unable to store document to file:///tmp/this.pdf (ErrCode 19468)`

But the file is indeed created at /tmp/this.pdf and I've confirmed via pdf viewer the file is perfect.

I am not sure why, but I am guessing the error is because I am not running a listener.  Perhaps someone else here will trouble-shoot that ;-)

Anyway, if you need to return an exit 0 from the conversion (e.g. puppet or chef may need that) , then run the convert like this:

`unoconv -f pdf /pathto/file.csv /pathto/file.pdf 2>/dev/null || /bin/true`

Lastly, unoconv csv conversion defaults to 'comma delimited', which fortunately works out for you.  Read the man page to see the import filter options if you want to use different and/or more than one delimiter.

Comment: You shouldnt provide the 2nd filename, it will automatically read from file.csv and write to file.pdf.   Also, the OP might like the `-f odt` option instead of pdf which produces a real spreadsheet file.

Comment: Appreciate the comments.  Yes output file path is optional, but nice to know it can go to a different directory or file name. The OP specifically wanted CSV to PDF format. PDF is the default output. Since you are allowed to mention the (unwanted) -f odt format, I can mention the (unnecessary) output file name ;-)

Comment: I actually get the same error with no output file created!

Comment: sorry it didn't work for you - but you got your soffice solution from Wilf - so you're set!